Text-colors not taken from the palette in material ui in angular
According to an issue from angular material, the contrast in the palette has no impact on label's text colors for components such as radio or checkbox buttons.
  <mat-radio-group color="primary" [(ngModel)]="filterDateType" (change)="changeDate()">
    <mat-radio-button value="create" class="mx-1 mx-xxl-2 py-1">تاریخ ایجاد
    </mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="update" class="mx-1 mx-xxl-2 py-1">تاریخ به‌روزرسانی
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>

The above is using the following material sass customization:
$light-primary-text: red;
$dark-primary-text: green;
$revolut-primary-palette: (
  100: #bcdffc,
  500: #2c9bf6,
  600: #2480db,
  700: #206ec8,
  800: #153e96,
  900: #002d81,
  contrast: (
    500: $light-primary-text,
    600: $light-primary-text,
    700: $light-primary-text,
    800: $dark-primary-text,
    900: $light-primary-text,
  ),
);
$primary: mat.define-palette($revolut-primary-palette, 900, 500, 800);
$accent: mat.define-palette(mat.$orange-palette, 900);
$light-theme: mat.define-light-theme(
  (
    color: (
      primary: $primary,
      accent: $accent,
    ),
    typography:
      mat.define-typography-config(
        $font-family: "IRANSans",
      ),
  )
);
@include mat.radio-theme($light-theme);

Given the above circumstances what would be the best way to change the foreground text in
said components?
Environment
Angular: 17.3.2
CDK/Material: 17.3.2

As stated here this is known bug.
There are currently two solutions at the moment:

Use this Repo: https://github.com/Plabbee/angular-material-contrast-fix until google fix it
Wait until 17.3.3 or above for fix from the official angular/material

